# Osx.Trojan.Genieo, what to do?

Tags: virus, macos, virus-removal

I ran ClamXav on my Mac today.

[image]

What do I do now, in particular with regards to the `Osx.Trojan.Genieo`?

---

I deleted both `.dmg` files (`InstallGenieo.dmg` and `InstallGenieo-2.dmg`, both dated `13 Nov 2013 09:30`) from my `Downloads` folder. Is that sufficient?

Comment: I see a -1. Am I in the wrong place? Please advise.

Comment: Maybe a better fit for superuser, but even then, probably better to post on the AV vendor's site. See: http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/are-questions-how-do-i-manually-get-rid-of-the-malware-on-topic . Maybe if it were phrased more generally, like what to do after finding a trojan/infection. But I'd search for duplicates first. Specific questions about your computer and a single virus are too localized.

Comment: @Gray Thanks for that. I also asked moderators to delete the question.

Comment: No problem. Understanding the culture of a SE site is always a challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.thesafemac.com/arg-genieo/
shows every file that is usually added. You probably only have the dmg's and are wise to avoid the genieo uninstaller, since it doesn't work & may actually add software instead.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is an appropriate place for virus removal, but I would imagine [a quick Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=Osx+Genieo) would [yield](http://www.wikihow.com/Delete-Genieo) some [possible](http://www.thesafemac.com/arg-genieo/) results [on how](http://botcrawl.com/how-to-remove-the-genieo-virus/) to [remove](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4497906?start=45&tstart=0) it.

Comment: Many thanks. I assume that considering that there are no file names left containing `Genieo`, I am now relatively safe from this? I prefer not to run (the linked) `Uninstall+Genieo.dmg`, because I haven't the faintest idea what it might do.